# Why are text not sharp when used in a animation instead of it being static

Tags: jquery, html, css, google-chrome, jssor

I am using jssor slider to display sliders on my page. When he text are inside a outer animated div, the display is sharp and not pixelated.

HTML:

```
<div u="slides" class="sliderHolder">
    <div>
        <img u="image" src="theImages/slider/homepage/1.png" alt="1" title="1" />
        <div u="caption" t="CLIP|L" class="sliderCapMain">
            <div class="sliderCapBG"></div>
            <div class="sliderCapText">
                <h1 class="sliderCapTextHdr">Healthy Cooking</h1>
                <br />
                <span class="sliderCapTextFtr">Discover simple solutions to cook delicious and healthy meals for you and your family. Cooking tips, how-to guides and more!</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Output:

[image]

But when I make the text in it's own animated div, it is very pixelated and not sharp.

HTML:

```
<div u="slides" class="sliderHolder">
    <div>
        <img u="image" src="theImages/slider/homepage/1.png" alt="1" title="1" />
        <div u="caption" t="CLIP|L" class="sliderCapMain">
            <div class="sliderCapBG"></div>
        </div>
        <div u="caption" class="sliderCapMain" t="ZMF|10">
            <div class="sliderCapText">
                <div class="sliderCapTextHdr">Healthy Cooking</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div u="caption" class="sliderCapMain" t="RTTL|BR">
            <div class="sliderCapTextF">
                <div class="sliderCapTextFtr">Discover simple solutions to cook delicious and healthy meals for you and your family. Cooking tips, how-to guides and more!</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Output:

[image]

As you can see the second image text are a bit pixelated.

CSS:

```
.sliderHolderMain
{
    position: relative;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    float: left;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 1100px;
    height: 347px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.sliderHolder
{
    cursor: move;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    width: 1100px;
    height: 337px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.sliderCapMain
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 225px;
    height: 337px;
    text-align: center;
}
.sliderCapBG
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.85);
    filter: alpha(opacity=85);
}
.sliderCapText
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 5%;
    left: 5%;
    right: 5%;
    color: #000;
    text-align: left;
}
.sliderCapTextF
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 15%;
    left: 5%;
    right: 5%;
    color: #000;
    text-align: left;
}
.sliderCapTextHdr
{
    color: #0074C9;
    font-size: larger;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.sliderCapTextFtr
{
    color: #000;
    font-size: small;
}
```

Please help me resolve it.

Comment: Which browser(s) does this happen on?

Comment: Surprisingly the issue is on Chrome. IE10 shows up fine (which is weird).

Comment: Can you post the CSS for this snippet?

Comment: Please try to set $HWA to false.

Answer (score 1):

this is because an elements gets pushed on its own drawing layer when animated via CSS. That layer makes animating a lot smoother but doesn't handle sharp text that well in Chrome.

Unfortunately, there's no way that I know of to solve this via CSS.

Comment: Any other way to achieve the sharpness?

Comment: Could you show what properties you're trying to animate? Not every animation forces a GPU layer.

Also, Javascript animations could be a solution if you want to preserve sharp text.

Answer (score 1):

To make a joke and possibly solve your problem:  Too many DIVs spoil the text.  I believe what is happening is that with the first example, the SPAN tag is enclosed inside of the previous DIV but in the second example the DIV with the text is covered by the previous DIVs thus making the text look fuzzy.

The rule of thumb here is: You only need ONE DIV for a given area.  Just like when the TABLE command was used to do everything - you are trying to break everything down into component parts and then put all of those parts into individual DIVs.  You do NOT need to do that.  For a given area you should just have one DIV and then use the rest of the HTML commands to achieve what you want.

There is no rule and it is no crime to use IDs and NAMEs in spans.  Just like with the DIVs - you can change the contents of the SPAN tag just like you can change the contents of the A, P, or any other tag.  Just give them unique IDs and you can then modify them if you wanted to change them.

Comment: I am not using any SPAN tag in my code. I do get your joke but how do you suggest I fix it :)

Comment: Think of the DIVs as flat panes of glass.  When you use multiple DIVs they are all one on top of the other so you have no way to know if your inner DIV is on top.  To ensure your DIV with the text is on top you have to include the style z-index like so:[p]

style="z-index:10;"[p]

This will pop those DIVs up to the top of everything and they should then show up crisp again.[p]

To back up though - your first example used the SPAN tag for the text. This ensured they would be presented on top of the DIV because then the DIV only affected the background.[p]

I hope this helps.  :-)

Comment: I felt I should add the following to my comment:  If you want to actually "SEE" a similar situation like what is happening here - download one of the free 3D animation programs.  Create two boxes that are exactly the same.  Color one blue and one red.  Put them at the same exact location (ie: 0,0,0).  What you will see is a mixture of both boxes (ie: some red - some blue). That is what is happening here.  Just in 2D rather than 3D and with more boxes(DIVS).  To be able to see the box you want to see - you have to move it a bit in front of the other boxes(DIVs).  I hope this is clear and helps.